# I connect my iPhone 5 IOS 10.3.1 but my Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't seem to detect it

Tags: iphone

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I'm trying to transfer pictures and videos from my iphone 5 IOS 10.3.1 to my Ubuntu 16.04 system but when I plug the phone in, it doesn't even show that I connect the phone to the computer.

How can I fix it? Is there something I could do that doesn't require installing a windows virtual machine?

Answer (score 5):

I have a new iPhone and have to use updated drivers from a ppa. Created mount point, pair phone, and mount with ifuse. I also then can drill down to /mnt/iPhone in Naulitus and see files.

```
sudo apt-get update
#ppa not required with 20.04 or newer
#sudo add-apt-repository ppa:martin-salbaba/ppa+libimobiledevice
sudo apt-get install ideviceinstaller libimobiledevice-utils ifuse libimobiledevice6  libplist3
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo mkdir /mnt/iPhone
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/iPhone 
sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-w /mnt/iPhone

idevicepair pair
ideviceinfo -d
ifuse /mnt/iPhone/
ls  /mnt/iPhone

to unmount:
fusermount -u /mnt/iPhone
idevicepair unpair
SUCCESS: Unpaired with device 78c......
```

See also & post #19:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1623666

Comment: Does not work from the `Info` line on. I couldn't manage to access my iphone with these instructions.

Comment: The Info command doesn't seem to serve any purpose here...

Comment: Removed the Info. It originally was #Info meaning ideviceinfo -d was the command for more info & optional. In my noted # is a note, but here It makes it large & bold so # removed, and then not a comment.

Answer (score -2):

There is an excellent tutorial.
https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc

You need to edit your ~/.bashrc file first and append this to the end:

```
[ ! -d "$HOME/usr/src" ] && mkdir -p "$HOME/usr/src"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${HOME}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
export CPATH="${HOME}/usr/include:${CPATH}"

export MANPATH="${HOME}/usr/share/man:${MANPATH}"

export PATH="${HOME}/usr/bin:${PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${HOME}/usr/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

After that, just log in again and follow the steps from the tutorial.

[image]