# After updating to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 I can't detect mobile phone through USB cable?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, drivers, 20.04, phone

I've tried everything and read most of the articles available but when I type

```
mtp-connect
mtp-folders
```

in terminal it lists all the folders in the phone so the cable and slots are working properly but something is broken after the update. Some articles mentioned using

```
adb devices
```

But that didn't work either as after the daemon is started it didn't list any devices.

I also tried installing `gvfs-backends` as mentioned in another article:

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends
```

But it gives this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gvfs-backends : Depends: libsmbclient (>= 2:4.10.0+dfsg) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also the HDD and the mouse are working fine just the mobile phone is facing problems.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What brand phone? I just did iPhone with Kubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/909988/i-connect-my-iphone-5-ios-10-3-1-but-my-ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-seem-to-detect-it/910094#910094

Comment: I used Mi A1 but the phone and the cable is working properly as I tried it on windows and other PC as well the HDD also connects well just the cell phone.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? I have the same thing, `adb` recognises the device and can interact with it fine so the device and cable are fine, but the file manager (nautilus) etc can't see it. Ubuntu 20.04 and phone running Android 9