# How long should idevicepair take to run?

Tags: 20.04, usb, iphone, idevices

I'm trying to connect an iPhone 10 to Ubuntu 20.04 via a USB cable. I've installed `libmobiledevice` successfully, and the phone is connected lightning cable to USB port.

When I run `sudo idevicepair pair` it doesn't give either a success or error message -- it just sits there blinking. It's been about 20 minutes now. I haven't received a Trust message on the iPhone.

Should it take a while for `idevicepair` to run? Or is no message after 20 minutes a sign of a problem? I don't mind letting it sit there all night, but I'm going to feel silly if it's pointless.

Comment: It should be instant. It is probably waiting for your phone (pairing is a 2 way event: you start it on one and accept it on the other). Do the options `systembuid` and `hostid` report an id?

Comment: Have you installed everything you need? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/909988/i-connect-my-iphone-5-ios-10-3-1-but-my-ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-seem-to-detect-it Updated to remove ppa, and just install from repository.