# iPhone is still recognized, but USB mount doesn't happen

Tags: mount, iphone

```
$ sudo apt update
...
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt full-upgrade
...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ uname -a
Linux ray-desktop 5.13.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 20 13:16:21 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The USB mount of an iPhone-8 (15.6.1) no longer shows up.

When I plug it in, the iPhone buzzes appropriately, and this shows up on the Ubuntu system:

```
$ sudo journalctl --follow
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=12a8, bcdDevice=10.04
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop kernel: usb 1-1: Product: iPhone
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop kernel: usb 1-1: SerialNumber: ece9a29270f4b897a925bd7c45ef3dde19b22a95
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop mtp-probe[85766]: checking bus 1, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop mtp-probe[85766]: bus: 1, device: 10 was not an MTP device
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop mtp-probe[85782]: checking bus 1, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Aug 27 18:53:05 ray-desktop mtp-probe[85782]: bus: 1, device: 10 was not an MTP device
```

But there's no obvious mount anywhere (e.g. `df`, `mount`, or the `Files` GUI).

This was working fine a few weeks ago.

Comment: I do not need ppa anymore as Ubuntu has drivers. https://askubuntu.com/questions/909988/i-connect-my-iphone-5-ios-10-3-1-but-my-ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-seem-to-detect-it/910094#910094

Comment: @oldfred, that answer hangs at `idevicepair pair`.  And it doesn't explain why it stopped working when it was okay a few weeks ago.

Comment: What OS/release are you using; you've only said you're using the 5.13 kernel.  No *supported* release of Ubuntu uses that kernel, so are you using Ubuntu ?

Comment: Did you unlock iphone? Mine usually says I have to do that. Then phone says "trust".

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/

Comment: @guiverc, it's not 21.10, it's 20.04 (fully updated), as indicated by the `uname` output.

Comment: Unplug your iPhone. `ls -l /dev >a`. Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you plug in the iPhone. `^C` to exit `journalctl`. `ls -l /dev >b;diff a b` should give you enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: @oldfred, if by "unlock" you mean I entered the pass-code to enter it, yes I did.  As I said, this used to work, but now it doesn't, but nothing is giving any error messages.

Comment: A fully upgraded 20.04 system will use the 5.4 kernel if using GA, or 5.15 if using HWE.  5.13 was from 21.10 & was replaced with the 5.15 kernel on 20.04 systems **before** 21.10 reached EOL (*or within a week for some cloud users using non-standard kernels*), so if using 20.04 your system is behind on upgrades (you should be using 20.04.5 with upgrades fully rolled out now, but they started rolling out just prior to 21.10's EOL!)  Your `uname` proves you're not using an *upgraded* system.

Comment: A 20.04 system upgraded is using `linux-generic-hwe-20.04 | 5.15.0.46.49~20.04.16  | focal-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x` where using the HWE kernel stack.

Comment: @guiverc, `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade` produces "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded".  — "*Your uname proves you're not using an upgraded system.*" — so what do I need to do to use an upgraded system?

Comment: Your details fit a Ubuntu 20.04 based system such as Linux Mint, but **not** a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system that has correct sources (*read the output of `sudo apt update` and check for missing lines, or check your sources; myself I find checking sources easier*).  When did you last perform `sudo apt full-upgrade` as `apt upgrade` has limitations on what it can install as is documented (ie. `man apt` & search for `full-upgrade` and it'll tell you it performs upgrade without the limitations on `upgrade`)...  Your provided details don't match 20.04 for an updated source.

Comment: @waltinator, the diff showed only changed timestamps on char, ptmx, chsm, and tty. ¶ I've included the journalctl output in the question.

Comment: @guiverc, `sudo apt full-upgrade` says "*0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.*".